# Parallelism in a sentence

Tags: verbs, tenses, parallelism

> A public authority was looking to improve productivity, transparency of information and better manage public funds.

What would be the correct way to write the above statement?

> A public authority was looking to improve productivity, offer more transparency in information and better manage public funds?

Comment: "A public authority was looking to improve productivity and transparency, and to manage public funds better."

Comment: Why do you think the original isn’t a correct way to express the sentence?

Comment: A public authority was looking to improve productivity and transparency, and **for a better way of managing** public funds."

Answer (score 0):

You should have a list of verbs or a list of nouns, so your second statement, with the list of verbs, is good. You could have a list of nouns with "A public authority is looking to improve productivity, transparency of information and management of public funds". The alternative in the comment is another possibility, but of the three I prefer your second statement.

Note that "looking" in this context means "intending" or "aiming", so it is correct without being changed to "looking forward".

Comment: thanks. if I use the verb "improves", is this statement fine ? A public authority improves productivity, information transparency and public funds management?

Comment: @Anand, the structure of the sentence is fine, but the meaning may not be what you want. As you have written it the meaning is most likely that the presence of the public authority results in the improvement of productivity etc for everyone. This would be part of an argument in favour of establishing such an authority. If you used present continuous like the question instead of simple present, i.e. "A public authority *is improving* productivity etc", it would mean that an unspecified authority is bringing about the improvements without specifying whose performance is being improved.